# how to use add_scalar while converting to onnx in QAT

Tags: pytorch

some problems occur in quantization aware train. i have known that add_scalar is not support in ONNX. Is it available to write other code to replace it. thx! here is my code

```py
class SPAB(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,
                 in_channels,
                 mid_channels=None,
                 out_channels=None,
                 bias=False):
        super(SPAB, self).__init__()
        if mid_channels is None:
            self.mid_channels = in_channels
        else:
            self.mid_channels = mid_channels
        if out_channels is None:
            self.out_channels = in_channels
        else:
            self.out_channels = out_channels
        
        self.in_channels = in_channels
        self.c1_r = Conv3XC(self.in_channels, self.mid_channels, gain1=2, s=1)
        self.c2_r = Conv3XC(self.mid_channels, self.mid_channels, gain1=2, s=1)
        self.c3_r = Conv3XC(self.mid_channels, self.out_channels, gain1=2, s=1)
        self.act1 = SiLU()
        # self.act2 = activation('relu', neg_slope=0.1, inplace=True)
        self.f_add1 = nn.quantized.FloatFunctional()
        self.f_add2 = nn.quantized.FloatFunctional()
        self.f_mul = nn.quantized.FloatFunctional()
        self.mean = -0.5 #torch.ones(size=(1, 1, 1, 1))*(-0.5)
        self.quant = torch.quantization.QuantStub()
        # self.dequant = torch.quantization.DeQuantStub()
    
    def forward(self, x):
        # self.mean = self.mean.to(x.device)
        # self.mean = self.quant(self.mean)
        out1 = (self.c1_r(x))
        out1_act = self.act1(out1)
        
        out2 = (self.c2_r(out1_act))
        out2_act = self.act1(out2)
        
        out3 = (self.c3_r(out2_act))
        
        # Create a tensor with the same type and shape as x, and move it to the same device
        # x = self.dequant(x)
        # if self.mean is None:
        # n,c,h,w = x.shape
        # device = x.device
        # mean = self.mean.repeat(n,c,h,w).contiguous().to(device) 
        # mean = self.quant(mean)
        # x = self.quant(x)
        
        # sim_att = torch.sigmoid(out3) - 0.5
        sim_att = self.f_add1.add_scalar(torch.sigmoid(out3), self.mean)
        out = self.f_mul.mul(self.f_add2.add(out3, x), sim_att)
        # out = (out3 + x) * sim_att
        # self.mean = self.dequant(self.mean)
        return out, out1, sim_att
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\usr1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\torch\onnx\utils.py", line 1596, in _export
    graph, params_dict, torch_out = _model_to_graph(
  File "C:\Users\usr1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\torch\onnx\utils.py", line 1139, in _model_to_graph
    graph = _optimize_graph(
  File "C:\Users\usr1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\torch\onnx\utils.py", line 677, in _optimize_graph
    graph = _C._jit_pass_onnx(graph, operator_export_type)
  File "C:\Users\usr1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\torch\onnx\utils.py", line 1950, in _run_symbolic_function
    raise errors.UnsupportedOperatorError(
torch.onnx.errors.UnsupportedOperatorError: Exporting the operator 'quantized::add_scalar' to ONNX opset version 13 is not supported. Please feel free to request support or submit a pull request on PyTorch GitHub: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues.
```